# code quality report is genrated in the artifact section but not in the pipeline section in Gitlab

Tags: phpcs

once pipeline completed the code quality report is generated  in the artifact section but not in the pipeline section in Gitlab. anyone suggest what is the issue.& code its worked properly on server.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Rzjw.png)

once pipeline completed the code quality report is generated  in the artifact section but not in the pipeline section in Gitlab. anyone suggest what is the issue.

Comment: Which pricing tier of GitLab are you using? [Code quality reports in CI pipelines requires at least a Premium subscription](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/testing/code_quality.html#features-per-tier).